# Loop though a query within a cfoutput of another query in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm attempting to write a function to find images from alternate versions of a product (these are books, so any product with the same "title" will work) by looping through any product that shares a title with the one that's missing an image.

I first run a query to get the products that will be displayed on the page (I know this part works fine, so I'm not concerned with it). When it's time to display an image, I first check to see if there is one for the chosen product.

If there is no image available, I want to run a second query for any products with the same "title" or "full title", and see if THEY have an available image. (which would be #SKU#.jpg, as you can see in the code) If an image is found for one of the alternate versions I save it to a variable, and once the loop finishes I display that chosen image.

If I STILL haven't found a product image, it instead shows our default "image not available" image.

```
<cfquery name="GetProductBasicInfo" datasource="#Request.Application.DataApp.datasource#" dbtype="odbc">
    SELECT product.Title, product.FullTitle, product.SKU, product.series, product.pubdate, productmarket.binding, product.productid, productmarket.productid
    FROM Product, productmarket
    WHERE product.productid = productmarket.productid 
        AND productmarket.Binding LIKE '#FORM.formFormat#' 
        AND product.series NOT IN ('Young Adult','childrens') 
        AND product.PubDate 
            BETWEEN '<cfoutput>#DatePart("m", FORM.formDate)#</cfoutput>/01/<cfoutput>#DatePart("yyyy", FORM.formDate)#</cfoutput>' 
            AND '<cfoutput>#DatePart("m", FORM.formDate)#</cfoutput>/28/<cfoutput>#DatePart("yyyy", FORM.formDate)#</cfoutput>' 
</cfquery> 

<cfoutput query="GetProductBasicInfo">
<!-- set of CFIF statements that determine if the current product has an image. If not, the following code is executed -->
    <cfquery name="altImages" datasource="#Request.Application.DataApp.datasource#" dbtype="odbc">
        SELECT product.SKU
        FROM Product
        WHERE product.title = '#Title#' OR product.fulltitle = '#FullTitle#'
    </cfquery>
    <cfset altPic = "">
    <cfloop query="altImages">
        <cfset altPicLocation = '#application.site.PWROOT#/client/products/prodimagetmb/#altImages.sku#.jpg'>
        <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath(altPicLocation)) eq 'true'>
             <cfset altPic = altPicLocation>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfif altPic NEQ "">
        <img src = "#altPic#" border = "0"> </a>
    <cfelse>
        <img src = "<cfoutput>#application.site.PWROOT#</cfoutput>/client/Products/prodimagedefault/tmbdefault/defaulttmb.jpg" border="0"> </a>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

When I run the above code, I get an error response. Due to "security concerns" I'm not allowed to have the Coldfusion admin pass or access to the error logs for the site I'm developing for (yes, I know how stupid that is) so I don't know what specific error I'm getting.

EDIT: The error has been resolved. It had to do with the formatting of my second query and a typo which I've fixed. The result is as inefficient as I'd feared though, so I'm still hoping to streamline it somehow.

EDIT: Added the code from the first query per request. "Product" is an absolutely *massive* table containing about 20k product records that our company sells, and about 35-40 columns for each. Productmarket is an associated table that contains about 40 more columns.

The first query searches by product type and publication date to define the contents of a page. The second query is triggered when an image with the name #SKU#.jpg doesn't exist for a given product; it searches for any other products with the exact same title (which would ahve been omitted from the first search, since it was the wrong type of product). If such a product exists, it checks to see if *that* #SKU#.jpg exists. If it does, it's assigned to a variable and used in place of the original.

Comment: Alternately, is there a more efficient way to do this? As long as I can check things with the same title for a potential image match, I'm okay with doing some new work or rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: Your second query doesn't make sense. You loop over the dataset and search in the same Product table.

Comment: Most likely, there's more efficient way: pull all the data in the 1st query, most likely using some sort of JOIN on these two tables. But from your current code it is unclear which exactly.

Comment: Bonus: I can bet you are not using `cfqueryparm` in that 'complex expression'. Aren't you?

Comment: To get the error without the administrator wrap your code in a `cftry\cfcatch` and then `cfmail` yourself the error

Comment: are you missing a join in your second query? probably not your current issue ,but will be an issue

Comment: Yep. If that is your actual code it is doing an [implicit cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) which could potentially return a *very* large resultset. As Sergii mentioned, it could probably be accomplished with a single join. Can you post the code for the first query?

Comment: Leigh , I've added the code for the first query, some of which comes from a form that is also included on the page.

The basic idea is that it first returns a set of products that fit the form criteria, then only runs the second query if there is no product image available for the item returned. I've confirmed it works far faster on pages with only a few missing images, so the slowdown comes from that looping second query...

My current optimization plan is to somehow find the alternate images for every returned item at once, but I'm not sure how to do that using a single query.

Comment: Sergii - Yeah, I haven't been. I inherited this site from a previous (lazy) admin and am learning ColdFusion so I can work with it. Most of these were even more malformed before I started, but there's still a long way to go getting them all up to spec...

Like I mentioned, I am locked out of the actual site backend by the host due to "security" concerns. I can't actually view the database, I have no admin login for the Coldfusion server, and I can't see the error logs. As a result I end up doing a lot of copy/paste of the existing code that I know works